# Webpack, CSS: where to put images?

Tags: webpack

I am really struggling to understand where I should put images/fonts to work with webpack so that they get bundled properly, and how to use them in my CSS with `url()`.

My webpack config says

```
entry: ['./main.js',],
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
},
```

It tells me where things should end up, but not where they come from. I guessed that it was the work of the loaders to find files everywhere in the project and copy them there. I have a loader for images:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
},
```

I created a directory `/public/images` with a `test.png` inside. I was hoping that it would end up in `public/dist/images/` or `/public/dist/`, but it doesn't.

And if it finally did, what should I put in my CSS to use the image as background ? `/public/dist/images/test.png` ? For the moment I have

```
.mydiv {
    background: url("/public/images/test.png");
}
```

and it is not showing. It seems that I cannot `require` even in css-modules.

Could you please clarify for me how that works ?

**Edit**: style loaders:

```
  {
    test: /\.css/,
    loaders: [
      'style-loader',
      `css-loader?${JSON.stringify({
        sourceMap: isDebug,
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: isDebug ? '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:3]' : '[hash:base64:4]',
        camelCase: 'dashes',
      })}`,
      'postcss-loader',
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"],
  },
```

Comment: Can you show us your loader for styles?

Comment: I added my style loaders in the question. In JS code I managed to have two images imported using a relative path (`require("../../public/images/test.png")`), and *one* of them was copied to `/public/dist/` when building. But in CSS, still no success.

Comment: You require images relative to the current file on the filesystem, just like with Javascript requires. Further reading http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/

Comment: @JulienD regarding your images: if one is small than 10K, it will be inlined into the bundle (that's what `limit=10000` means). As for styles: Webpack only works when you `require` your styles inside your JS (or if you have a specific `entry` point for them). And without extra configuration, the CSS will be included in the (JS) bundle and not saved to separate .css files.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! @robertklep The explanation about the 10K limit was extremely helpful. I thought it was a constraint on the file size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as much i understand you don't need to do any thing, webpack will take care of it for you. Let say you have a folder call images some where and you want this

```
.mydiv {
    background: url("/public/images/test.png");
}
```

webpack will bundle this in dist folder you, it will also change it name with something else and even path in url. in my case i had url like this

```
background: url("../../assets/webpack+angular.png")
```

and when i run webpack i got a file called `dist/f1305c1f7292179760078b1efdee3ffa.png`
and my url look like this

```
url(/f1305c1f7292179760078b1efdee3ffa.png);
```

and everything works just fine. You don't need to use require in css.

Comment: Indeed it worked. The div I was trying to fill did not show it for some obscure reason (probably related to Material), but another one did. Thanks. Your few simple lines and the comments to my post should be on top of their unreadable docs.